# Dll built with visual studio 2019 with v141_xp tool chain fails to load on xp when loaded from visual studio 2010 built exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2019

## Problem

I have an exe that was built with Visual Studio 2010 that I cannot change.
I have a DLL that I do control and would like to upgrade the tool chain as much as I can while maintaining Windows XP compatibility.  It looks like the proper solution is to build the dll with the platform toolset v141_xp with Visual Studio 2019.

With these build settings, the loadlibrary call fails with error 998 on Windows XP, it does not fail on Windows 10 and works fine.

How do I load a dll built with platform toolset v141_xp from an app built with Visual Studio 2010 successfully?

## What I have Tried

When I build a skeleton test program that just loads the dll, if I build it with Visual Studio 2010, same result, 998 error on Windows XP and a working version on Windows 10.
When I build an empty MFC DLL with the project template provided by Visual Studio, I get the same result as the dll I am trying to load with my test program.

The most interesting thing is that if I build this test program with Visual Studio 2019 with toolset v141_xp the test program operates correctly on both Windows XP and Windows 10.  So I know that the dll is compatible with XP with those build settings.

Comment: I think you need to stick with the v100 toolchain and not use `v141_xp` at all. I believe this will cause a situation where you have the runtime from 2010 and 2019 in the same program. You can't allocate memory from one CRT and free it in a different CRT so unless your dll isolates memory allocations and deallocations from the program this will lead to UB. This is all assuming we are talking about native standard c++ and not .NET / CLR

Comment: Do you see the possibility of linking statically to the runtime with /MT? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=msvc-160

Comment: Yes, both the dll and the executable are statically linked with the /MT switch.

Comment: `998` is `ERROR_NOACCESS`, likely coming from a `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` in the loader. From [Q196069](https://web.archive.org/web/20121120102320/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196069): "*To troubleshoot the LoadLibrary() failure, run the application under a debugger and enable first chance exception handling for the C0000005 Access Violation exception [...]*".

Comment: You should clearly specify your problem ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) .

Comment: @CristiFati I will work on this, is there a good way to do it with visual studio projects? Because the code is basically the dll template provided by VS and a four line program to load it with LoadLibrary, but built with different versions and trying to run on different OS's, one of which is unsupported by MS :(\]

Comment: @rileymat "*basically the dll template provided by VS*" That one links the CRT dynamically by default, but you wrote that you are using `/MT` instead. The problem likely lies in such "small" changes, which no one can guess if you don't post a complete, reproducible example, including all build settings. FWIW just loading a DLL built with VS 2019 from an EXE built with VS 2010 works fine on Windows XP, so there must be another difference elsewhere.

Comment: @dxiv yes, I understand this, like I said is there a good way to post entire minimal visual studio projects with settings and such?

Comment: @rileymat The code should be small enough to post here, as for the `vcxproj` files a `diff` vs. the default ones generated by VS should do. Or, put the minimal projects on github and post the link here.